# OLAP cube powering Excel Pivot. What's a better solution?

Tags: excel, olap, olap-cube

I'm looking to build a dynamic data environment for non-technical marketers. 
I want to provide large sets of data in an Excel pivot table form so even marketers without analytics/technical backgrounds can access relevant performance information. I'm trying for avoid non-excel front ends since I don't want users to have to constantly export data when they need to manipulate it in some way.

My first thought was to just throw together an OLAP cube populated with pre-aggregated data, but I got pushback from the IT team as OLAP is "obsolete." I don't disagree with them - there are definitely faster data processing architectures out there.

So my question is this: are there any other ways to structure the data so that marketers can access it easily but still manipulate it to some degree in Excel? I'm working with probably 50-100m rows of data and need the ability to scale dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my thoughts.

Really the question could be thrown back at your IT team.  Your first thought was to throw together an OLAP cube.  IT didn't like this.  If they're so achingly hip that they consider OLAP "obsolete", what do they suggest as a better, more up-to-date alternative?

Or, to put it a different way - what is the substance of their objection to an OLAP solution? (I'm assuming there is one beyond "MS gave us an awesome presentation of PowerPivot/Azure tabular, with really great free snacks and coffee").

Your requirements are pretty clear:

1. Easy access for non-technical people
2. Structured data so that they don't have to interpret the raw data
3. Access through Excel
4. Scalability

I'll be paying close attention to any other answers to your question, because I'm always interested in finding out that I don't know something; but personally I haven't come across a better solution to these requirements than OLAP.

What makes me suspicious of the "post-OLAP" sentiment is related to point (2) in the list above.  Non-technical users can tend to think of the cube data they consume as being somehow effortlessly produced, by some kind of magic.  That in itself is an indicator of success, demonstrating just how easy it is for users to get what they want from a well-designed OLAP system.

But this effortlessness is an illusion: to structure the raw data into this form takes design effort, and the resulting structure incorporates design decisions and assertions: that is how it can be easy to use, because the hard stuff has been encapsulated in the cube design.

I have a definite Han Solo-like bad feeling about "post-OLAP": that it amounts to pandering to this illusion of effortless transformation of data into a usable form, and propagates further illusions.

Under OLAP, users get their wonderful magic usable data structure, and the hard work is done out of sight by developers like you or me.  Perhaps we get something wrong so that they can't see data exactly as they'd like to - but at least the users can then talk to us and ask for what they do want.

My impression of the "post-OLAP" sales pitch is that it tries to dispense with the design work.  We don't need those pesky expensive developers, we don't need to make specific design decisions (which necessarily enable some functionality while precluding some other functionality), we don't need cube-processing time-lags.  We can somehow deliver this:

- Input any data you like.  Don't worry if it's completely unstructured or full of dirt!
- Any scale
- Immediate access to analytics without ETL/processing delays
- Somehow, the output is usable, structured data.  Structured by... no-one in particular.  The user can structure it as they like, but somehow this will be easy

Call me cynical, but this sounds like magical thinking to me.